# How do I get the HTML of divs that have been sorted using this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the HTML div I'm needing to be sorted:

```
<div id="divtosort">
    <div class="datasort" data-order="2">2</div>
    <div class="datasort" data-order="4">4</div>
    <div class="datasort" data-order="1">1</div>
    <div class="datasort" data-order="3">3</div>
</div>
```

And I'm using this function to sort the div:

```
function getSorted(selector, attrName) {
    return $($(selector).toArray().sort(function(a, b){
        var aVal = parseInt(a.getAttribute(attrName)),
            bVal = parseInt(b.getAttribute(attrName));
        return aVal - bVal;
    }));
}
```

When I enter this line into the console:

```
getSorted('.datasort', 'data-order')
```

I get this result:

```
[ <div class=​"datasort" data-order=​"1">1</div>, <div class=​"datasort" data-order=​"2">2​</div>, <div class=​"datasort" data-order=​"3">​3​</div>​, <div class=​"datasort" data-order=​"4">​4​</div>​]
```

The question is, how do I turn this result into actual HTML that I can replace the existing HTML with?

Comment: `a.data('order')` should be better than `a.getAttribute(attrName)`. 
Any HTML data can be added to the current render via `.innerHTML`. This is how it works: [w3schools innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) or you can use `append` [.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: @JaxCze jQuery's [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) is better than [`Element.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) *because*...?

Answer (score 2):

> The question is, how do I turn this result into actual HTML that I can replace the existing HTML with?

You already have that. In this example I'm using jQuery's [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function which will **replace** the HTML content of the node it's called on:

```js
function getSorted(selector, attrName) {
    return $($(selector).toArray().sort(function(a, b){
        var aVal = parseInt(a.getAttribute(attrName)),
            bVal = parseInt(b.getAttribute(attrName));
        return aVal - bVal;
    }));
}


var sorted = getSorted('.datasort', 'data-order');

$('#divtosort').html(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divtosort">
    <div class="datasort" data-order="2">2</div>
    <div class="datasort" data-order="4">4</div>
    <div class="datasort" data-order="1">1</div>
    <div class="datasort" data-order="3">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eq7cdhnk/1/)

#### HTML

```
<div id="divtosort">
    <div class="datasort" data-order="2">2</div>
    <div class="datasort" data-order="4">4</div>
    <div class="datasort" data-order="1">1</div>
    <div class="datasort" data-order="3">3</div>
</div>
```

#### Jquery

```
function getSorted(selector, attrName) {
    return $($(selector).toArray().sort(function(a, b){
        var aVal = parseInt(a.getAttribute(attrName)),
            bVal = parseInt(b.getAttribute(attrName));
        return aVal - bVal;
    }));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divtosort").html(getSorted('.datasort', 'data-order'));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var $sordedElemets = getSorted('.datasort', 'data-order');

$("#divtosort").append( $sordedElemets );
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/cexikaf/1/edit?html,css,js,output)***

Answer (score -1):

Try storing the result of `getSorted('.datasort', 'data-order')` in a variable 
 then empty the div with Id `divtosort` after that append `sortedList` to the div.

Code would look somewhat like this -

`var sortedList = getSorted('.datasort', 'data-order');`

`$('#divtosort').empty();`

`$('#divtosort').append(sortedList);`